# How to scroll Listview nested in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, scrollable

When I use two nested Listviews and ListView.builder it still scroll, but the child Listview.builder with the shirnkSwap property cannot be scrolled anymore, but I don't want to use the height attribute in the widget container because it is very ugly.

Flutter 1.9.4 SDK

**// My Home Screen**

````
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEEF0F2),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF396DF0),
        elevation: 0,
        leading: LeadinguttonIcon(),
        title: Text('TheGoal'),
        actions: <Widget>[ActionIconButton()],
      ),
      body:
          ListView(children: <Widget>[TopHomeScreenBody(), BottomHomeScreen()]),
    );
  }
}```

**//  TopHomeScreenBody**

```class TopHomeScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: BodyClipper(),
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xFF396DF0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 22, left: 22, bottom: 30),
        height: 250,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[MainText(), SubText()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

**// BottomHomeScreen** 


```class BottomHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
//  IT CAN SCROLL WHEN ADD HEIGHT BUT I
//  DONT WANT USE HEIGHT HERE BECAUSE VERY UGLY APP
//    height: 400,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFEEF0F2),
      ),
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return BottomGoalTitle(
            text: '${goalList[index].text}',
            decsText: '${goalList[index].decsText}',
            color: goalList[index].color,
            icon: goalList[index].icon,
          );
        },
        itemCount: goalList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

Thank you for reading. Hope your help!

Comment: still wondering why you have to use ListView on the parent widget like this, ListView(children: <Widget>[TopHomeScreenBody(), BottomHomeScreen()]), why dont you change it to Column ?

Comment: If i change it to column in horizontal screen the topscreenbottom() will fix size at the top and cant scroll, and the content bottomhomescreen() just in little bit area with censored by topscreenbody(). I try change to column and in listview.builder(bottomhomescreen) wrap with expand widget, it can scroll best in vertical screen, but in horizontal screen is bad.

Comment: sorry, dont really understand what you mean, but why do you need scrollable widget inside a scrollable widget ? like ListView inside a ListView, i dont think its the best practice of using ListView, if you already determined the consecutive widget on the Home Screen, then i think using Colum is the best practice, and if there's some problem with the children, you have to fix the children, not changing the Column, as for me, i always use Column inside a SingleChildScrollView, if you can provide me the UI that you want to create, i'll try to help you create it

Comment: Can you pick me on facebook, or social net like that, i need 10 reputation for post images, i am newbie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean that you dont want your `listview.builder` to scroll try adding this `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: I want all listview.builder can scroll. Sr for my question make mistake.

Comment: I was understood, In body of scaffold i use column inside singlechildscrollview, and in column i have 2 custom widget, tophomescreen and bottomscreen widget, in bottomhomescreen have listview.builder, i push  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), all widget in column can scroll, thanks you so much.